# How long does it take to get from Reykjavik to Vik with a super jeep during winter?

Tags: driving, iceland

Assuming I have a superjeep how long does it take (approximately) to get from Reykjavik to Vik during the month of December, and when's the best time to start if I want light the entire drive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have not done this journey in a superjeep, only in normal transportation in summer months. But I can tell you that it is usually around a 2.5 hour journey. Its a fairly pleasant drive in my experience.

During winter, Iceland only has around 4 hours of daylight per day. At worst, on the Winter Solstice (22nd December in 2015) [the sun will rise at 11:23 and set 15:30 in Reykjavik.](http://www.timeanddate.com/sun/iceland/reykjavik?month=12&year=2015)

Comment: That was useful, so in that case I should start at around 11:30 from Reykjavik, which doesn't seem to have much traffic, right?

Comment: Uhm I don't think daylight is the only concern during December. I'll give you that even during my years in Iceland the amount of snow during winter has varied greatly, but **never underestimate a blizzard**. At least with a superjeep the car won't be as likely blown off the road, though ;)